# SQL - How to determine fiscal quarter when quarters are determined by # of days?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a situation I've never seen before, where a fiscal year started on 2/4/2018 is broken down like this:

Q1 - 111 days long (2/4/2018 - 5/26/2018)
Q2 - 83 days long (5/27/2018 - 8/18/2018)
Q3 - 83 days long (8/19/2018 - 11/10/2018)
Q4 - 83 days long (11/11/2018 - 2/2/2019)

That is considered FY 2018

The next year, FY 2019, starts on 2/3/2019 and has the same quarter lengths, and Q4 would end on 2/1/2020. FY 2020 then starts on 2/2/2020.

I need to be able to determine the fiscal year and quarter for a given date (@testdate in my code below). The following works for FY 2018:

```
declare @startdate  date    = '2/4/2018'
,       @startyear  int     = 2018
,       @testdate   date    = '2/5/2018'

select  'Fiscal Year'       = case when datediff(dd, @startdate, @testdate) between 0   and 363 then @startyear else 0 end

select  'Fiscal Quarter'    = case when datediff(dd, @startdate, @testdate) between 0   and 111 then 'Q1'
                                   when datediff(dd, @startdate, @testdate) between 112 and 195 then 'Q2'
                                   when datediff(dd, @startdate, @testdate) between 196 and 279 then 'Q3'
                                   when datediff(dd, @startdate, @testdate) between 280 and 363 then 'Q4'
                                   else 'Q0' end
```

The problem is when I have a date after the end of FY 2018 Q4 (2/2/2019). I'm not sure how to get any date past that to automatically fall into the day ranges (0-111, 112-195, 196-279, 280-363). Manually, for FY 2019, I can subtract 364 from the date and that seems to work. For FY 2020, I can subtract 364 * 2 (728). For each year after that, keep subtracting 364 * n where n is the number of years between whatever future fiscal year and FY 2018.

This works for FY 2020:

```
declare @startdate  date    = '2/4/2018'
,       @startyear  int     = 2018
,       @testdate   date    = '5/28/2020'
,       @testdate2  date    = null

set @testdate2 = dateadd(d, -728, @testdate)

select  'Fiscal Year'       = case when datediff(dd, @startdate, @testdate2) between 0   and 363 then @startyear + 2 else 0 end

select  'Fiscal Quarter'    = case when datediff(dd, @startdate, @testdate2) between 0   and 111 then 'Q1'
                                   when datediff(dd, @startdate, @testdate2) between 112 and 195 then 'Q2'
                                   when datediff(dd, @startdate, @testdate2) between 196 and 279 then 'Q3'
                                   when datediff(dd, @startdate, @testdate2) between 280 and 363 then 'Q4'
                                   else 'Q0' end
```

I'm guessing the solution revolves around how to calculate that -728 automatically (which would be 364 * n), and how to increment @startyear accordingly.

Any ideas on how to determine the fiscal year and quarter for a given date with these odd fiscal quarters?

Thanks!

Comment: Hello Jeff - would it be a good idea to make a table fiscal year( quarter, startDate,endDate)? Like that you can add quarters when needed and not worry if the tax office calculate differently from one year to the next.

Comment: that's what I do currently. I was hoping to stop having to update a table or query each year.

Comment: I'm afraid that you're going to spend time perfecting a calculation for the tax office to decide to do it differently next year. Entering 4 lines of 3 values once a year must take less than minutes.

Comment: The fiscal quarters will never change. They're always 111, 83, 83 and 83 days long, starting on 2/4/2018. I work for a very large company, and updating a table for a production database requires a lot of effort.

Comment: You mention 364 days, but 111 + 83 + 83 + 83 = 360 days. 

It looks like a 0-based count discrepancy, but just wanted to double check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution which does an integer division to get the number of years after 2018. We then subtract 364 times this number from `DATEDIFF` the base year to get the number of days from the start of the current tax year. We can use your case statement to determine the quarter.

> ```
> create function dbo.quarter (@date date)
> returns varchar(100)
> as
> begin
> declare @days int = datediff(dd,'2018-04-02',@date)
> declare @years int = @days / 364
> set @days  = @days - (@years * 364)
> set @years = @years + 2018
> declare @quarter char(2)= case 
>       when @days between 0   and 111 then 'Q1'
>       when @days between 112 and 195 then 'Q2'
>       when @days between 196 and 279 then 'Q3'
>       when @days between 280 and 363 then 'Q4'
>       else 'Q0' end
>       return concat(@years,'-', @quarter)
>  end
> ```

> ```
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> select dbo.quarter('5/4/2018') quarter;
> select dbo.quarter('2020-04-02') quarter;
> select dbo.quarter('2022-01-24') quarter;
> select dbo.quarter(GETDATE()) quarter;
> select dbo.quarter('2021-12-25') quarter;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> | quarter |
> | :------ |
> | 2018-Q1 |
>
> | quarter |
> | :------ |
> | 2020-Q1 |
>
> | quarter |
> | :------ |
> | 2021-Q4 |
>
> | quarter |
> | :------ |
> | 2021-Q4 |
>
> | quarter |
> | :------ |
> | 2021-Q3 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=64bd89574caa43860d3ea3d69e327746)*